# Nordic Bluetooth 5.0 Breakout board

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I am highly interested in developing a project involving bluetooth 5.0 on a nordic device, namely the NRF52840. However the package of this device is beyond my capabilities/kit for soldering.

I have found a breakout board, BL654 Series, but again it uses under the package pins, which is not possible. I am struggling to find any breakout possibilities for a bluetooth 5.0 nordic board with 32+ GPIOs which can be hand soldered.

Does anyone know of any alternatives by nordic with this? or a method by which I could maybe integrate the above Laird solution or other solution?

Comment: I suggest that you stop trying to find a solution to use the chip by itself and look for a **module**. When I Google NRF52840 I see plenty of development boards and modules. A module will have all the "difficult" stuff (small connections, special components, antenna, RF stuff) taken care off and the connections are easy to solder onto. So get a **module**!

Comment: Hi Bimpelrekkie, the above breakout board BL654, is a module. But it still uses a QFN still soldering solution, ie soldering underneath the package. I’ve found bluetooth 5.0 nordic modules but none which will be easily solderable, this is what i’m hoping somebody may have a remedy for! :)

Comment: Yeah, well the NRF52840 is a complex device with a lot of connections and that means the module is complex (to solder) as well. You could consider a simpler module but that may not have BT5, only BT4 (some ESP modules). If you do need BT5 from the NRF52840 then use an evaluation board, it has jumpers for all connections. Such boards are expensive though.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, do you know of an example board with 5.0 with headers?

Comment: How about BL652?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Filo, doesn't quite have enough Filo. I've just found a manufacturing solution for the above BL654.

Answer (score 3):

> I am highly interested in developing a project involving bluetooth 5.0
>   on a nordic device, namely the NRF52840. However the package of this
>   device is beyond my capabilities/kit for soldering

Start by purchasing an [NRF52840 development board](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Getting-started-with-the-nRF52840-Development-Kit): -

[image]

You can do an awful lot of development using this then, when you are ready, get PCBs made and get someone with the right tools to solder them up for you.